# translate3d lags on iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, css, translate3d

I'm working on a project for iOS devices and I am using translate3d to move an object around the page when a user drags it.

When viewed with Chrome (or even Safari) you can see the box moves around very smoothly, but when viewed on an iPhone or iPad the box doesn't move smoothly at all. When using CSS transitions with translate3d on iOS the transitions are very smooth so I don't understand why this isn't. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my javascript: (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls4uc/10/)

```
var tStart, loc, rdy;
$(".box").bind("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
    tStart = e.type == "mousedown" ? event.clientX : event.touches[0].pageX;
    tStartY = e.type == "mousedown" ? event.clientY : event.touches[0].pageY;
    tStartTranslate = getTranslateParams($(this), "x");
    tStartTranslateY = getTranslateParams($(this), "y");
    $(".log").text(tStart);
    rdy=true;
});
$(".box").bind("mousemove touchmove", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!rdy){return;}
    loc = tStart - parseInt(e.type == "mousemove" ? event.clientX : event.touches[0].pageX);
    locY = tStartY - parseInt(e.type == "mousemove" ? event.clientY : event.touches[0].pageY);
    $(this).css({"-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + parseInt(Math.ceil(tStartTranslate) + (-loc), 10) + "px," + parseInt(Math.ceil(tStartTranslateY) + (-locY), 10) + "px,0)"});
});

function getTranslateParams(obj, xy) {
    var paramsArray = $(obj).css('-webkit-transform').substring(7, $(obj).css('-webkit-transform').indexOf(')')).split(',');
    if (xy !== "x" && xy !== "y") {
        return false;
    }
    return xy == "x" ? paramsArray[4] : paramsArray[5];
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use the translate3d for this? It seems to me it would make more sense to just set the top and left values with a position of absolute.

Comment: I was using translate3d because after the user releases the object it will snap into a spot, so I could use CSS transitions to animate the object to a certain spot (which is smoother than animating top/left).

Comment: Depending on application requirements, I might still argue that you would be better off using top/left. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls4uc/12/) which I believe is much more simplified and in the end, it will be much easier to determine the box's position.

Comment: That works good in Chrome but I run into the same problem on an iPhone of choppy movements.

Answer (score 0):

use -webkit-perspective:1000;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden on elements in .box

For example

'

```
.box li{
-webkit-perspective:1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
}
```

'

It's works well in ios6, but ios7...